# Python Pandas: MultiIndex groupby second level of columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I'm trying to group rows by multiple columns. 
What I want to achieve can be illustrated by this small example:

```
import pandas as pd

col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A','A','B','B'],['a','b','c','d']])

df = pd.DataFrame([ [1,2,3,3],
                    [4,2,2,2],
                    [6,4,2,2],
                    [1,2,4,4],
                    [3,8,4,4],
                    [1,2,3,3]], columns = col_index)
```

DataFrame created by this looks like this:

```
   A     B   
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  3
1  4  2  2  2
2  6  4  2  2
3  1  2  4  4
4  3  8  4  4
5  1  2  3  3
```

I would like to group by 'c' and 'd', actually whole 'B'
This gives me "KeyError: 'c' "

```
#something like this
df.groupby(['c','d'], axis = 1, level = 1)
#or like this
df.groupby('B', axis = 1, level = 0)
```

I tried searching for answer but I can't seem to find any.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it by resetting the columns first:

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.droplevel(0), axis=1,inplace=False).groupby(['c','d']).sum()
Out[531]: 
      a   b
c d        
2 2  10   6
3 3   2   4
4 4   4  10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify the 2-level multi-indices explicitly.

```
df.groupby([("B","c"), ("B", "d")])
```